# compiling C and asm on vs2017

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, compiler-errors, x86

I am trying to interface C and asm code on VS2017. C main program calls a function and that function is defined into my asm file.
File name is "main.c", asm file name is "eser.asm"

If I try to run the same code on VS on another computer (windows) it works perfectly

Here is the main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sommalungstringhe(char *s1, char *s2);


int main()
{
    char s1[255] = "simone e' il migliore";
    char s2[255] = "chissa' a fare cosa";


    printf("%d", sommalungstringhe(s1, s2));
    getchar();
}
```

And it's the eser.asm file

```
.586
.model flat
.code

_sommalungstringhe proc

push ebp
mov ebp,esp
push edi
push esi
push ebx

mov esi,0 
mov edi,0
mov ebx,dword ptr[ebp+8]
mov ecx,dword ptr [ebp+12]

ciclo:
cmp byte ptr[ebx+edi],0
je azzera_edi
inc esi
inc edi
jmp ciclo

azzera_edi:
mov edi,0
jmp conta_seconda

conta_seconda:
cmp byte ptr[ecx+edi],0
je fine_ciclo
inc esi
inc edi
jmp conta_seconda

fine_ciclo:
mov eax,esi
pop ebx
pop esi
pop edi
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
ret



_sommalungstringhe endp

end
```

I tried compiling it and it give me some error.

Two errors that I get when I try compiling it as separate source files:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3721 The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Release\eser.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Taeser.asm" exited with code 1.  tmp_prj C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets  69
```

Second error is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   A1000   cannot open file : eser.asm tmp_prj \\mac\Home\Desktop\tmp_prj\MASM 1
```

I've also configured VS for treating asm file as source file.

I'm using vs2017 on macbook pro with parallels

UPDATE: solved, it was permission problems.. tried to create and build program into another drive, worked!

Comment: Likely using wrong calling convention? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/984x0h58(v=vs.140)

Comment: @Lundin I do not think it's a calling error, because the same piece of code works well on windows pc.

Comment: It says “cannot open file : eser.asm.” Are you sure that file is readable and in the correct location?  This seems to be more of a configuration problem than a code problem.  Also make sure you are compiling your program as 32 bit code as this is 32 bit assembly code.

Comment: @fuz Yes surely.. Configured VS in many ways, but always this problem, and yes i'm compiling it as a 32 bit

Comment: @arst3k As you have not posted the Visual Studio configuration or the exact steps you did to set up this project, it is not possible to say what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Is this related to file permissions on what is likely a SAMBA mount on `\\mac` . Do you have permission to create new files in that directory? What if you try building this project from the local drive. Does it work?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks solved, it was permission problems.. tried to build program into another drive, worked!

Comment: @arst3k Would you mind posting this as an answer so future readers can receive the wisdom you gained?